# Determine windows process Uptime

Tags: windows, process

Is there a way to determine the 'uptime' of a process in Windows. I would prefer to use powershell and not a third party tool, and I would like process name, start time and process Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-Process -Name <process name> | FT Name,StartTime,Id`

or for all running processes:

`Get-Process | FT Name,StartTime,Id`

You can see more about the cmdlet [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Success! Thank you for the extra documation too. Stack Exchange won't let me upvote your response. *sad face*